# Loss function increasing instead of decreasing

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have been trying to make my own neural networks from scratch. After some time, I made it, but I run into a problem I cannot solve. I have been following a [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/coding-a-2-layer-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-4dd022d19fd2) which shows how to do this. The problem I run into, was how my network updates weights and biases. Well, I know that gradient descent won't be always decreasing loss and for a few epochs it might even increase a bit, bit it still should decrease and work much better than mine does. Sometimes the whole process gets stuck on loss 9 and 13 and it cannot get out of it. I have checked many tutorials, videos and websites, but I couldn't find anything wrong in my code.
`self.activate`, `self.dactivate`, `self.loss` and `self.dloss`:

```py
# sigmoid
self.activate = lambda x: np.divide(1, 1 + np.exp(-x))
self.dactivate = lambda x: np.multiply(self.activate(x), (1 - self.activate(x)))

# relu
self.activate = lambda x: np.where(x > 0, x, 0)
self.dactivate = lambda x: np.where(x > 0, 1, 0)

# loss I use (cross-entropy)
clip = lambda x: np.clip(x, 1e-10, 1 - 1e-10) # it's used to squeeze x into a probability between 0 and 1 (which I think is required)
self.loss = lambda x, y: -(np.sum(np.multiply(y, np.log(clip(x))) + np.multiply(1 - y, np.log(1 - clip(x))))/y.shape[0])
self.dloss = lambda x, y: -(np.divide(y, clip(x)) - np.divide(1 - y, 1 - clip(x)))
```

The code I use for forwardpropagation:

```py
self.activate(np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.biases) # it's an example for first hidden layer
```

And that's the code for backpropagation:

First part, in `DenseNeuralNetwork` class:

```py
last_derivative = self.dloss(output, y)

for layer in reversed(self.layers):
    last_derivative = layer.backward(last_derivative, self.lr)
```

And the second part, in `Dense` class:

```py
def backward(self, last_derivative, lr):
    w = self.weights

    dfunction = self.dactivate(last_derivative)
    d_w = np.dot(self.layer_input.T, dfunction) * (1./self.layer_input.shape[1])
    d_b = (1./self.layer_input.shape[1]) * np.dot(np.ones((self.biases.shape[0], last_derivative.shape[0])), last_derivative)

    self.weights -= np.multiply(lr, d_w)
    self.biases -= np.multiply(lr, d_b)

    return np.dot(dfunction, w.T)
```

I have also made a [repl](https://repl.it/repls/SoreTriflingGnuassembler) so you can check the whole code and run it without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

line 12

```
self.dloss = lambda x, y: -(np.divide(y, clip(x)) - np.divide(1 - y, 1 - clip(x)))
```

if you're going to clip x, you shoud clip y too.
I mean there are some ways to implement this, but if you are going to use this way.
change to

```
self.dloss = lambda x, y: -(np.divide(clip(y), clip(x)) - np.divide(1 - clip(y), 1 - clip(x)))
```

#### 2.

line 75

```
dfunction = self.dactivate(last_derivative)
```

this back propagation part is just wrong.
change to

```
dfunction = last_derivative*self.dactivate(np.dot(self.layer_input, self.weights) + self.biases)
```

#### 3.

line 77

```
d_b = (1./self.layer_input.shape[1]) * np.dot(np.ones((self.biases.shape[0], last_derivative.shape[0])), last_derivative)
```

last_derivative should be dfunction. I think this is just a mistake.
change to

```
d_b = (1./self.layer_input.shape[1]) * np.dot(np.ones((self.biases.shape[0], last_derivative.shape[0])), dfunction)
```

#### 4.

line 85

```
self.weights = np.random.randn(neurons, self.neurons) * np.divide(6, np.sqrt(self.neurons * neurons))
self.biases = np.random.randn(1, self.neurons) * np.divide(6, np.sqrt(self.neurons * neurons))
```

Not sure where you are going with this, but I think the initialized values are too big. We're not doing precise hypertuning, so I just made it small.

```
self.weights = np.random.randn(neurons, self.neurons) * np.divide(6, np.sqrt(self.neurons * neurons)) / 100
self.biases = np.random.randn(1, self.neurons) * np.divide(6, np.sqrt(self.neurons * neurons)) / 100
```

#### All good now

After this I changed the learning rate to 0.01 because it was to slow, and it worked fine.
I think you are misunderstanding back propagation. You should probably double check how it works. The other parts are ok I think.

Comment: Thanks! I love you man! I was trying to solve this problem for few weeks, but I couldn't get anyehwere close to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by your training data. Either it is too small or too many diverse labels (What i get from your code from the link you share).

I re-run your code several times and it produce different training performance. Sometimes the loss keeps decreasing until last epoch, some times it keep increasing, in one time it decreased until some point and it increasing. (With minimum loss achieved of 0.5)

I think it is your training data that matters this time. The learning rate is good enough though (Assuming you did the calculation for Linear combination, back propagation, etc right).